# Unblock Utorrents ports

Tags: firewall, bittorrent, ports

Recently our company has blocked all incoming ports by default. Since then I am unable to download from torrent sites. Our network engineers allowed to open the ports for me in which uTorrent is using to download. So i looked at my utorrent and have incoming port unblocked but still unable to download. How to check which ports utorrent is using?

Answer (score 0):

Go in:

> Options -> Preferences -> Connections

and see what value is inside the *Port used for incoming connections* textbox. Make sure also the "Randomize port each start" checkbox is disabled.

Comment: I have them opened that port and disabled Randomize but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You must tell your network engineers to open e.g. 36184 port for you and you must be sure that this port is never changed in your uTorrent application

[image]